# Controlling Bin Widths in Altair

Tags: python, histogram, visualization, altair

I have a set of numbers that I'd like to plot on a histogram.

Say:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_numbers = np.random.normal(size = 1000)
plt.hist(my_numbers)
```

If I want to control the size and range of the bins I could do this:

```py
plt.hist(my_numbers, bins=np.arange(-4,4.5,0.5))
```

Now, if I want to plot a histogram in Altair the code below will do, but how do I control the size and range of the bins in Altair?

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

my_numbers_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Integers': my_numbers})

alt.Chart(my_numbers_df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("Integers", bin = True),
    y = 'count()',
)
```

I have searched Altair's docs but all their explanations and sample charts (that I could find) just said `bin = True` with no further modification.

Appreciate any pointers :)

Comment: P.S. I did try to add charts to the question but I don't have enough reputation to do that apparently

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As demonstrated briefly in the [Bin transforms](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/bin.html) section of the documentation, you can pass an [`alt.Bin()`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.BinParams.html) instance to fine-tune the binning parameters.

The equivalent of your matplotlib histogram would be something like this:

```
alt.Chart(my_numbers_df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("Integers", bin=alt.Bin(extent=[-4, 4], step=0.5)),
    y='count()',
)
```

[image]

Comment: That link got moved: here's the updated one if you are looking https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/bin.html